# Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host or a different Error

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu, code-injection

I'm trying to build an extension, and I'm having trouble injecting a function.

This is the link that I'm trying to work on, I suspect that the blob at the start is the problem.

```
blob:https://web.whatsapp.com/29d92fb3-d8e1-4c84-89af-b51668f5d2b3
```

This is my manifest.json file:

```
 {
    "name": "Image rotator",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "description": "An extension to rotate images in web page.",
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "src/background.js"
      },
      "permissions": ["contextMenus","scripting","storage", "declarativeContent", "activeTab","<all_urls>"],
      "host_permissions": [
        "*://web.whatsapp.com/*"
      ]
      
}
```

This is my background.js file:

```js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "id": "rotateImage",
    "title": "Rotate Image",
    "contexts": ["image"]
  })
});

function injectedFunc() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("img").style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
};

try {
  chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: {
        tabId: tab.id
      },
      function: injectedFunc
    });
  });
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

In this version, I get this error:

> Error in event handler: TypeError: Error in invocation of scripting.executeScript(scripting.ScriptInjection injection, optional function callback): Error at parameter 'injection': Error at property 'target': Missing required property 'tabId'.

If I change the onClicked method to this version:

```js
try{
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
    if(info.menuItemId === "rotateImage"){
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: {tabId: tab.id},
        function: injectedFunc
      });}
  });
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot access contents of the page. Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host.

Comment: Instead of the property `function`, shouldn't it be `func`? Based off of the docs [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#type-ScriptInjection).

Comment: @cactus12 No, according to [this](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#programmatic) doc.

Comment: Did you click inside a tab? Because tab prop might be undefined, try to get active tab instead (`const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });`)

Comment: @BorisTB Instead of declaring the tab argument in the function's arguments? I tried that, I still get the second error presented in the post.

Comment: The second variant is correct, so you must be invoking it in the tab that is not a http or https. Another possibility is that it's an iframe. Move `<all_urls>` from `permissions` to `host_permissions`.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm trying to invoke this in `blob:https://web.whatsapp.com/cf92547e-f905-4c45-a72e-194251794573` kind of URL. I moved the `<all_urls>` to `host_permissions` and still get the second error.

Comment: `blob:` is not a http or https URL so you can't do it.

Comment: @wOxxOm Edge/Chrome 99 and I get this error: `Error at parameter 'injection': Unexpected property: 'matchOriginAsFallback'.` I've added it to the executeScript: `chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        matchOriginAsFallback: true,...`

Comment: Ah, no, it's only supported for chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts... Try opening a new bug report on https://crbug.com for your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second variant was the correct one, according to [this](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#injecting-in-related-frames) I needed to add `"match_origin_as_fallback": true,` to the manifest.json file inside "content_script" to make the browser be able to read the blob URL.

But it still didn't work, I needed to add the injected code to a different file than the background.js.

With some help from Reddit (Thanks Ibrahim_AA), the sendMessage and onMessage [API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#external) did the work.
Here is the full solution:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Image rotator",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "description": "An extension to rotate images in web page.",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "src/background.js"
  },
  "permissions": ["contextMenus","scripting"],
  "host_permissions": [
    "*://web.whatsapp.com/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://web.whatsapp.com/*"],
      "match_origin_as_fallback": true,
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

background.js:

```js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        "id": "rotateImage",
        "title": "Rotate Image",
        "contexts": ["image"]
    })
});

try{
    chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
        if(info.menuItemId === "rotateImage"){
            chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
                    type: "rotateImage",
                });
            });
        }
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
```

contentScript.js

```js
function rotateImage() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (msg.type === 'rotateImage') {
        rotateImage();
    }
});
```

Hope it helps anyone that comes across this problem.